# Given a convex subset $A$ of a normed space, a point $x_0 \notin A$, is there an hyperplane passing through $x_0$ and not intersecting $A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

my background is an undergraduate degree in mathematics got at an european university, I'm doing some self study in functional analysis and I'm reading from cover to cover Rynne's Introduction to linear functional analysis, a really usefull book for self study because for every exercise in the text there is a proposed solution at the end of the book.

I think one of the solution proposed by the author is not correct, I'd like an opinion if my reasoning is correct, or if you have other inputs it would be appreciated.

The text of the exercise:

Exercise 5.11: Suppose that X is a real, normed space, A ⊂ X is a non-empty,
convex set, $x_0$ ∈ X, and U is a linear subspace of X such that
A ∩ ($x_0$ + U ) = ø . Show that there exists a closed hyperplane H in
X containing $x_0$ + U such that A ∩ H = ø .
[Hint: let B = {$x_0$} and adapt the proof of Theorem 5.30.]

My Reasoning (spoiler, i think the question is not well posed):

> The hypothesis are not strong enough to guarantee the existence of such hyperplane $H$, let's consider this convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$ : $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x \leq 0\} \setminus \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x=0 , y \leq 0 \}$, the point $x_0=(0,0)$ and the subspace $U=\{(0,0)\}$.
> It's possible to prove that no hyperplane contains $x_0$ and does not intersect with $A$, I think we need more conditions on $A$ to be able to guarantee the existence of the hyperplane $H$ (for example it should suffice to hypothesize that $A$ is open).

If someone is curious about the solution proposed by the author I could edit the post and include it, I have not done that at the moment because I should also include the proof of a theorem that is quite long. I will however include the statement of the theorem cited in the hint:

Theorem 5.30 (Separation Theorem):Suppose that X is a real or complex normed space and A, B ⊂ X are non-empty, disjoint, convex sets.

(a) If A is open then there exists f ∈ X and γ ∈ R such that f (a) < γ ≤  f (b), with a ∈ A, b ∈ B.

(b) If A is compact and B is closed then there exists f ∈ X  and δ > 0 such
that f (a) ≤ γ − δ < γ + δ ≤ f (b), with a ∈ A, b ∈ B.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. To me it looks like the exercise is missing one assumption. Maybe this can be inferred from the solution...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, the solution use a certain lemma that requires $A$ to be open, so I think it's the text exercise that just miss an assumption.